# Tab navigation with React but not React-Native?

Tags: reactjs

I'm into PWA development, and I'd like to use React components to build my UI, but not React-native components (otherwise why write PWAs...).
So I am looking for an equivalent to the top-tab-navigator component found here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/
but without any React-Native dependency!

Changing pages by swiping would be great, even without a visual effect.
So far, I found React components to put tabs on displays inside pages, but nothing with navigator characteristics (full screen views, event on page change, ...).
Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you!

So far, I found React components to put tabs on displays inside pages, but nothing with navigator characteristics (full screen views, event on page change, ...).

Comment: Does this help? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/

Comment: Thank you
I have already found this page. Towards the end of given page there are something called "Nav tabs" and the LinkTab element, but even if the click on a tab causes a request, it is necessary to display the fetched information in a view, well resized, and to reproduce the tabs on the loaded page, etc.. still a lot of work necessary, while a more complete tab-based navigation structure or component must exist somewhere